# reverse engineering with correlation between two random Variables

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, standard-deviation, correlation, covariance

If some one give me correlation between two random variables $X$ and $Y$,  then how I can find the distribution of $X$ and $Y$.?

Comment: The correlation coefficient does not provide enough information to retrieve the entire cdf.

Comment: i need approximation analysis ...we can predict distribution ..

Comment: You could reject an infinite number of distributions, if that would help. Unfortunately, that would still leave an infinite number of distributions that may be suitable.

Answer (score 2):

very easy you can't.
For example if I know that $Cor(X,Y)=0$ then there are lots of possible choices for the distribution of $X$, the distribution of $Y$ and also for the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$. To give you some examples:

- $(X,Y)$ could have a two dimensional normal distribution with uncorrelated components
- $X$ could have a uniform distribution on $(-1,1)$ and $Y=X^2$. In this case $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated but not independent.
- $X$ and $Y$ could have any distribution (normal, exponential, binomial, poisson,...) and be independent. In this case their correlation is also zero.

In general you need to know the marginal distributions of $(X,Y)$ (i.e the distribution of $X$ and the distribution of $Y$) **and in addition** you need to know the dependence structure (aka **Copula**) of $X$ and $Y$ to be able to get the joint distribution (see [Sklar's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)#Sklar.27s_theorem)).

The correlation does not even specify the dependence structure (only in special cases, when e.g. the Copula is a Gauß Copula).